# Why is a _react-native-otp-verify_ library call throwing an 'is not a function' error?

Tags: javascript, react-native, sms-verification

I am trying to use a ReactNative package, [react-native-otp-verify](https://github.com/faizalshap/react-native-otp-verify) to implement automatic SMS verification. At this point, I am getting an error though, that I need help with on how to resolve, even though I tried to use it exactly as prescribed in the docs.

Below is also the expo log:

```html
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _reactNativeOtpVerify.default.getHash is not a function. (In '_reactNativeOtpVerify.default.getHash()', '_reactNativeOtpVerify.default.getHash' is undefined)]
at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at [native code]:null in dispatchAction
at http://192.168.226.60:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:286125:34 in loadResourcesAndDataAsync$
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Code sample of where I am using the package:

```html
.
.
.


import RNOtpVerify from 'react-native-otp-verify';


function HomeScreen(props) {

    const getHash = () =>
        RNOtpVerify.getHash()
            .then(console.log)
            .catch(console.log);

    const startListeningForOtp = () =>
        RNOtpVerify.getOtp()
            .then(p => RNOtpVerify.addListener(this.otpHandler))
            .catch(p => console.log(p));

    const otpHandler = (message) => {
        const otp = /(\d{4})/g.exec(message)[1];
        this.setState({ otp });
        RNOtpVerify.removeListener();
        Keyboard.dismiss();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        RNOtpVerify.removeListener();
    });
   
   .
   .
   .
```

At this point, I am also welcoming suggestions for suitable SMS verification alternatives. I have a custom sign-in/signup system, and I want to augment SMS verification to the user registration. Is such a thing possible with only a client library?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

@skj This library seems to have some issues but actually they use this library under the hood `react-native-sms-retriever` . You can follow their documentation and do it yourself without using another library. Check it out on npmjs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-retriever)

Answer (score 0):

react-native-otp-verify is only for android. You can use a condition like

```
if (Platform.OS === "android"){ RNOtpVerify.getHash() }
```